# junit 5 is not mocking java.net.http.HttpClient.send

Tags: java, maven, junit, mockito, junit5

I am trying to write junit 5 code in a java maven project(not a springboot project) , which is calling an API and extracting response and creating a file. But when I tried to mock the API calling, junit still calls actual API, which is not the desired behaviour. Can someone help to identify issue here?

I followed this link to write below unit tests [How to mock HttpClient's send method in junit 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69768931/how-to-mock-httpclients-send-method-in-junit-5)

Actual service code -

```
public class MyService {

    public void create(String apiHost, String firstPage) {
        HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.newBuilder()
                .version(HttpClient.Version.HTTP_2)
                .connectTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(30))
                .build();
        HttpRequest httpRequest = getHttpRequest(apiHost, firstPage);
 
        MyResponse myResponse = invokeApi(httpClient, httpRequest);
        List<ResponseData> responseDataList = new ArrayList<>(myResponse.getData());
        while (null != myResponse.getLinks().getNext()) {

            myResponse = invokeApi(httpClient, getHttpRequest(apiHost, invokeApi.getLinks().getNext()));
            locationDetailsList.addAll(invokeApi.getData());
        }

        createFile(fileName, responseDataList);
    }

    private HttpRequest getHttpRequest(String apiHost, String pageUri) {
        return HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .GET()
                .uri(URI.create(apiHost + pageUri))
                .build();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    MyResponse invokeApi(HttpClient httpClient, HttpRequest httpRequest) {
        HttpResponse<Supplier<MyResponse>> result = httpClient.send(httpRequest, new JsonBodyHandler<>(MyResponse.class));
        return result.body().get();
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    void createFile(String fileName, List<ResponseData> responseDataList) {
        Path filePath = Paths.get("test/path" + fileName);
        Files.createFile(filePath);
        Files.writeString(filePath, header + System.lineSeparator(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        for (ResponseData responseData : responseDataList) {
            Files.writeString(filePath, responseData + System.lineSeparator(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
        }
    }
```

Junit 5 code -

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    @Mock
    HttpResponse<Object> httpResponse;

    @Mock
    private HttpRequest request;

    @Mock
    Supplier<MyResponse> myResponseSupplier;


    @Test
    void testSendMessage() throws Exception {

        when(httpClient.send(any(),any())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
        when(httpResponse.body()).thenReturn(myResponseSupplier);
        when(myResponseSupplier.get()).thenReturn(getMyResponse());
        myService.create("https://www.google.com", "/v1/test?page_size=100");
        verify(httpClient).send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
}
```

In the above junit code when "myService.createmyMnt" is executed it actually tried to invoke https://test.com instead of mocking the call.

Answer (score 2):

You are facing this because you are mocking the same dependencies 2 times.
Here what i mean:

```
 @Mock
 private HttpClient httpClient;
```

And then in beforeEach you again are mocking your dependency

```
httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
```

I recommend choosing the approach that you need and don't mock 2 times.
Here where you are mocking and use @InjectMocks. Also we need to add annotation @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class) this will handle initMocks(this) and we won't need to add it(this annotation helps to mocks be properly injected).

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    @Mock
    HttpResponse<Object> httpResponse;

    @Mock
    private HttpRequest request;

    @Test
    void testSendMessage() throws Exception {
        MyResponse myResponse=new MyResponse();

        when(httpClient.send(any(),any())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
        when(myService.invokeApi(httpClient,request)).thenReturn(myResponse);
        myService.createmyMnt("https://test.com", "/v1/test?page_size=100");
        verify(httpClient).send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
    }
}
```

or use constructor injection like:

```
class MyServiceTests {

    private MyService myService;
    private HttpClient httpClient;
    private HttpResponse<Supplier<MyResponse>> httpResponse;
    private HttpRequest request;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        httpClient = mock(HttpClient.class);
        httpResponse = mock(HttpResponse.class);
        request = mock(HttpRequest.class);
        myService = new MyService();
    }

    @Test
    void testSendMessage() throws Exception {
        MyResponse myResponse = new MyResponse();

        when(httpClient.send(any(), any())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
        when(httpResponse.body()).thenReturn(() -> myResponse);

        myService.create("https://test.com", "/v1/test?page_size=100");

        verify(httpClient).send(request, new JsonBodyHandler<>(MyResponse.class));
    }
}
```

---

According to the comments try this please:

```
    @ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
class MyServiceTests {

    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myService;

    @Mock
    private HttpClient httpClient;

    @Mock
    private HttpResponse<Supplier<MyResponse>> httpResponse;

    @Mock
    private HttpRequest request;

    @Mock
    private Supplier<MyResponse> myResponseSupplier;

    @Test
    void testSendMessage() throws Exception {
        MyResponse myResponse = getMyResponse();

        when(httpClient.send(any(), any())).thenReturn(httpResponse);
        when(httpResponse.body()).thenReturn(() -> myResponseSupplier);
        when(myResponseSupplier.get()).thenReturn(myResponse);

        myService.create("https://www.google.com", "/v1/test?page_size=100");

        verify(httpClient).send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
      
    }

    private MyResponse getMyResponse() {
        return new MyResponse();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did remove mocking in 2 places as you suggested but getting nullpointer in the line "return result.body().get()" of method invokeApi , because "java.net.http.HttpResponse.body()" is null

Comment: Congrats! You have new exception and you can go forward. You need to stub HttpResponse.body() with when() using powermockito or mockito-inline(which i suggest) because it`s static method.

Comment: Thanks, you are right I missed stubbing HttpResponse.body(). But I still notice that it's actually calling the API instead of mocking , if I provide any dummy URL instead of actual API it gives "java.net.ConnectException". I wanted it to mock the API calling instead of calling actual API.

Comment: Maybe you had a typo with createmyMnt() and you need to write create(). seems strange to me

Comment: That was typo while posting question on here, updated the code to fix typo's. Still code is failing at "return result.body().get();" because of jackson parsing exception when code executes supplier.get() method, it's giving 404 response when supplier.get is executed and jackson parse fails due to invalid html content of 404 response

Comment: Note: 
You mocked HttpResponse<Object> httpResponse; but in your method you are using 
HttpResponse<Supplier<MyResponse>> httpResponse;
so you need to pass supplier 
when(httpResponse.body()).thenReturn(() -> myResponse);

Comment: Which I am already doing if you see my updated code above, I am returning a mocked supplier. So the main issue I mentioned in code still exists, the junit is calling actual API instead of mocking the behaviour and along with that now it's failing to get response from supplier also

Comment: Try my last *updated* version of the code. If it won't work. I can`t help with this. because code is not reproducible and i can not debug this

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, it didn't work. It's still trying to connect to google.com and supplier.get fails to parse